# 2004 Georgia Tech Varsity Multiple Choice Version B Question 10

Tags: matrices, determinant

I was reviewing this test and came over this question:

How many distinct solutions $x$ are there for the equation det($A-xI$) $=0$ where det stands for determinant, $I$ is the identity matrix, and $A$ is the matrix

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & -3 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
    1 & -2 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
It looks really computational (4 x 4 matrix determinant), so I am asking you guys if there is an elegant way to solve this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions when possible, rather than posting images.  Images can't be searched, and aren't accessible to people using screen readers.  If you need some help on how to format mathematics on this site, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I used snag.gy, so it's a screenshot. Dunno if that changes something. I didn't use mathjax because I don't know how to use matrices.

Comment: Matrices are explained in the tutorial. The goal of this site is for people who have problems to be able to search for their solutions.  I don't think a search that shows up a problem on snag.gy(if that is possible) will turn up an answer on MSE.

Comment: Ok. Hadn't read the answers yet. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To evaluate $\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
1-x & 0 & -3 & 0\\
0 & 2-x & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 3-x & 0\\
1 & -2 & 0 & 1-x
\end{array}\right|$, identify a row or column with as few nonzero entries as possible, e.g. the rightmost column. The determinant can be written as $\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
1-x & 0 & -3\\
1 & 0 & 3-x\\
1 & -2 & 0
\end{array}\right|+\left(1-x\right)\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
1-x & 0 & -3\\
0 & 2-x & 0\\
1 & 0 & 3-x
\end{array}\right|$. Now let's repeat: $$\left|\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -3\\
0 & 3-x
\end{array}\right|+2\left|\begin{array}{cc}
1-x & -3\\
1 & 3-x
\end{array}\right|+\left(1-x\right)\left(\left|\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -3\\
2-x & 0
\end{array}\right|+\left(3-x\right)\left|\begin{array}{cc}
1-x & 0\\
0 & 2-x
\end{array}\right|\right)=2((1-x)(3-x)+3)+(1-x)(2-x)(3+(3-x)(1-x)).$$You'll notice one quadratic obviously divides that; the whole quartic simplifies to $(4-3x+x^2)(6-4x+x^2)$. You can now find all eigenvalues from the quadratic formula; there are four roots in $\Bbb C$< none of them real because $$a=1,\,b=-4,\,c=6\implies b^2-4ac<0;\,a=1,\,b=-3,\,c=4\implies b^2-4ac<0.$$

Comment: Thanks! I feel dumb now :P

Comment: I don't understand one bit. Why $$\begin{vmatrix} 1-x & 0 & -3 \\ 1 & 0 & 3-x \\ 1 & -2 & 0 \\ \end{vmatrix}$$?

Comment: Sorry. That sounded a bit rude. I meant to say 'there is one part i dont understand'.

Comment: I notice that the above matrix removes the rightmost column and the 2nd row.

Comment: @asdf334 If you go down the rightmost column, the first nonzero entry is $1$, which doesn't require a sign change; and then we eliminate its row and column.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* Permute the second and the third rows and columns of $A$ to get
$$
\pmatrix{1&-3&0&0\\ 1&3&0&0\\ 0&0&2&1\\ 1&0&-2&1}.
$$